# cmake: regenerate file with each build

Tags: cmake

`generated.h` is created by a script replaced with `touch` for now. How can I achieve that this file is regenrated each time I run `make`? Calling `rm` like in the below example produces error.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(MyProject)

set_source_files_properties(generated.h PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

add_executable(jr
    jr.cpp
    generated.h
    )

add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT generated.h
        COMMAND rm generated.h
        COMMAND touch generated.h
        )
```

Comment: Instead of `add_custom_command` use `add_custom_target`: it will be executed every time build is run.

Comment: If I make the change the file will be not generated.

Comment: Hm, have you tried: `add_custom_target(regenerate COMMAND touch generated.h)`, `add_dependencies(jr regenerate)`? If you want to remove the file before `touch`, use `COMMAND rm -f generated.h`.

Comment: I have tried, but got: `jr.cpp:1:23: fatal error: generated.h: No such file or directory #include "generated.h"`

Comment: For find created include file you need `include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})`.

Comment: It works. Thank you! If you post the answer I will accept it happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `add_custom_command` use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_target.html): it will be executed every time build is run:

```
add_custom_target(regenerate
    COMMAND rm -f generated.h # Remove file if it exists.
    COMMAND touch generated.h
)

# Force executable to be compiled after regeneration takes a place
add_dependencies(jr regenerate)

# You need to hint compiler about location of the header file generated.
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```